# Sub setting dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have `Dataframe` with three columns as
`Date, Id, pages`. In `pages` values are according to time of visit. So I want customers who visit `page A` after `page B` on the same date.

As in the image below `ID 2` visit `page A` after `B` on `2 Nov`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
A_after_B = lambda x: x.eq('B').idxmax() < x.eq('A').idxmax()

m1 = df['Page'].isin(['A', 'B'])
m2 = df.groupby(['ID', 'Date'])['Page'].transform(A_after_B)

out = df.loc[m1 & m2]
print(out)

# Output:
   ID    Date Page
5   2  02-Nov    B
6   2  02-Nov    A
```

Setup:

```
data = {'ID': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
        'Date': ['01-Nov', '01-Nov', '01-Nov', '01-Nov',
                 '01-Nov', '02-Nov', '02-Nov', '02-Nov'],
        'Page': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'A']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but what if any other page say C,D is present between B and A on same date.But I want to ignore them and get the same solution

Comment: @BikashJha. I updated my answer according to your comment. Can you check it please?